# Communicate between threads with pipes

Tags: c++, multithreading, pipe

I am not very good at C++. So what I am trying to do is that I am trying to divide a vector into chunks and send it through the pipe to child threads and they sort and then send it back through pipes. However, I am having trouble sending the data to the child thread, somehow the child thread would read a very large number or zero instead of the array's size.

The thread_arg is the struct where I pass in the arguments for the child thread, this is where I pass in pipes which I used in the childThreadFunction.

I would really appreciate any help/advice!!!

```
using namespace std;

struct thread_arg {
    int parent_child[2];
    int child_parent[2];
    int n;
};

void *childThreadFunction(void *arguments) {
    cout << "in child thread function" << endl;
    struct thread_arg *args = (struct thread_arg *)arguments;

    // child process takes its own chunk of data and sort it
    close(args->parent_child[1]);
    int n;
    read(args->parent_child[0], &n, sizeof(int));
***this is where it's acting weird***
    cout << "array size: " << n << endl;
    pthread_exit(0);
    return NULL;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    vector<long long> numbers;

    for (int i=0; i<fileNames.size(); i++) {
        // reading each file and adding that to the vector numbers
        fstream file;
        file.open(fileNames[i], ios::in);
        if (!file) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error: File with the name: %s doesn't exist.", fileNames[i]);
            exit(1);
        }
        string tempNum;
        while(getline(file, tempNum)) {
            if (isNumber(tempNum)) {

                numbers.push_back(stoll(tempNum));
            }
        }
    }
    if (nprocesses == 1) {
        numbers = bubbleSort(numbers);
        for (int i = 0; i < numbers.size(); i++) {
            cout << numbers[i] << endl;
        }
        return 0;
    }

    // downpipe will be from 0 to (nprocesses-1)
    // uppipe will be from nprocesses to 2*nprocesses
    int fd[2*nprocesses][2];
    for (int i=0; i<(2*nprocesses); i++) {
        if (pipe(fd[i]) < 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error with creating the pipes");
            exit(1);
        }
    }

    size_t const chunk_size = numbers.size() / nprocesses;
    if (threads) {  // threads

        vector<thread_arg> thread_args;

        pthread_t thr[nprocesses];

        int s;
        for (int i = 0; i < nprocesses; i++) {
            struct thread_arg child_arg;
            pipe(child_arg.parent_child);
            pipe(child_arg.child_parent);
            thread_args.push_back(child_arg);
            s = pthread_create(&thr[i], NULL, childThreadFunction, (void *)&child_arg);
            if (s != 0) {
                fprintf(stderr, "Error creating the child thread");
            }
        }

        vector<int> sizes;

        for (int i = 0; i < nprocesses; i++) {
            std::vector<long long> splitVec;
            if (i+1 < nprocesses) {
                std::vector<long long> splitVec1(numbers.begin() + (chunk_size * i), numbers.begin() + (chunk_size * (i + 1)));
                splitVec = splitVec1;
            } else {
                std::vector<long long> splitVec2(numbers.begin() + (chunk_size * i), numbers.end());
                splitVec = splitVec2;
            }
            // sending the chuck of numbers to the down pipe for children to read
            //close(thread_args[i].parent_child[0]);
            int n = splitVec.size();
            sizes.push_back(n);
            long long arr[n];
            copy(splitVec.begin(), splitVec.end(), arr);
            write(thread_args[i].parent_child[1], &n, sizeof(int));
            write(thread_args[i].parent_child[1], arr, sizeof(long long)*n);
            close(thread_args[i].parent_child[1]);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < nprocesses; i++) {
            pthread_join(thr[i], NULL);
        }
    }
}
;
```

[This is the output of the above code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KXOgH.png), I am supposed to get 25 four times, but instead I get some random large number.

Comment: There is no such thing as a "child thread". There are just threads. You close half the pipe in the child thread and then likely `read` gets an error because there is nothing left to write to. You need to check functions like `read` and `write` for errors and log them as this will make the problem obvious.

Comment: Thank you for the comment, but that is the weird part, even after I comment out all the close, I still get the wrong size read from the thread. Only the first read is correct. And I am certain that I am writing the correct number, but the thread cannot read the same number from the pipe

Comment: If you don't capture the return values of your `read()` and `write()` calls into a variable and examine that variable, then you'll have no idea if those calls succeeded, or how many bytes they actually read/wrote from/to your buffer.  Then you end up asking questions on StackOverflow about why your program is acting weird... :)

Comment: hahaha, got it, I will work on that!

Comment: Update: They are all expected values, writing size returns 4 bytes which means sense, and reading size also returns 4 bytes.

Comment: Given this task at-hand, the pipes are near-pointless anyway. The thread arguments can just be the partition source data, including the starting point and length, assigned to each worker respectively. Since no worker is 'sorting' anything besides their own partition, it is a pure waste of IO to replicate that data across pipes even once, much less multiple times. Yes, you can drive a nail with a screwdriver, but why.

Comment: See [mre]. You should do your own debugging. Anyway, you set a worker thread argument as a pointer to an auto variable.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with how I initialized my arg struct for the thread, I need to dynamically allocate it instead of declaring it on the stack because threads don't have access to the main's stack.

P.S. I understand that we don't need pipes to pass information, it was just my assignment requirement.